# How do I properly move a window with a region?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, region

I've just started looking into window regions, and I'm trying to create an elliptical window that I can move by dragging the client area. Unfortunately, when I drag the window, the window flashes back and forth from the ellipse to the normal window (as if I never called `SetWindowRgn`), and back, repeatedly and rapidly.

I read on MSDN that I have to call `SetWindowRgn(nullptr);`, then move the window, then reset the region, which I have already done in my code. I move the window by calling `SetWindowPos` with `SWP_NOZORDER`, `SWP_NOSIZE`, and `SWP_NOREDRAW`, and I've tried adding on all of `SWP_NOSENDCHANGING`, `SWP_DEFERERASE`, and `SWP_NOCOPYBITS` as well, to no avail.

Here's my window procedure, with emphasis on `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. I know it won't work if I release the button outside of the window; I was planning to deal with that after this worked. I also left out error checking. It's pretty obvious that the calls do work, though, because the window does move as I drag it.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static bool moving{};

    switch (msg) {
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: {
            moving = true;
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONUP: {
            moving = false;
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
            static POINT old{0, 0};

            if (moving) {
                RECT r;
                GetWindowRect(hwnd, &r);

                int x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
                int y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

                RECT newPos;
                newPos.left = r.left + x - old.x;
                newPos.top = r.top + y - old.y;

                SetWindowRgn(hwnd, nullptr, FALSE);

                SetWindowPos(hwnd, nullptr, newPos.left, newPos.top, 0, 0,
                    SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOREDRAW
                );

                SetWindowRgn(hwnd, CreateEllipticRgn(200, 200, 600, 400), FALSE);
            }

            old.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            old.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I've also tried calling `ValidateRgn(hwnd, nullptr);` at the end of `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, which doesn't change anything. As well, I've tried wrapping the `DefWindowProc` call in a condition that just returns 0 if `moving` is set in order to see whether it was just some other message being sent that was messing with it, but that resulted in the window doing nothing when dragged. I then applied that condition to `WM_PAINT` and `WM_ERASEBKGND` handlers, but that resulted in the same flickering problem when dragged.

In order to test it more easily, here's [full code](http://pastebin.com/T4ap4XSt) (just rudimentary window creation etc). Am I going about moving the window the right way? Is there some message or something that I should handle, but don't? This is happening on Window 7 Ultimate N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much easier way to handle the move logic is to handle the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, returning `HTCAPTION`. This makes Windows handle all the move logic for you.